# Java JAI - Error: One factory fails for the operation "Mosaic"

Tags: java, imaging, jai

i'm using Java Advanced Imaging. I already have the tiles and want to put all the tiles together in one PlanarImage. The code below returns the following error message:

*Error: One factory fails for the operation "Mosaic"
Exception in thread "main" javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "Mosaic"*

```
public static void loadTiles() {
    RenderedImage[] source = new RenderedImage[new File("C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\tiles\\67").listFiles().length-1];

    System.out.println(source.length);

    ImageLayout il = new ImageLayout(0, 0, 3306, 2336);
    RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(JAI.KEY_IMAGE_LAYOUT, il);
    RenderedOp ro = MosaicDescriptor.create(source, MosaicDescriptor.MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY, null, null, null, null, rh);

    System.out.println(ro.getData());        // <<<< Throws Exception

    PlanarImage pi = ro.createInstance();
    File outputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\dgrimm\\workspace\\tiles\\output");
    System.out.println(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());

    JAI.create("filestore", pi, outputFile.getAbsolutePath(), "png");

}
```

Can you help me to fix the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have declared your array that stores the tiles. You haven't actually loaded the tiles into the array.

Comment: i knew it long before you commented.